# C# Console Collision

Tags: c#, console-application, collision-detection

Currently I am making a console game (a rougelike) and I needed some advice on the collision events. I need to tell if there is a wall (▒) next to the player (@) and if so disallow the player from moving in that direction.
Does anyone have any ideas about how I could do this with the console in C#?

If needed I can provide some of my code.

Comment: "although I would rather not do so" Why not?

Comment: What defined there to be a wall in the first place? Did it appear out from the empty space? No memory allocated bit that indicates it is a wall? (Player.X - 1 == Wall) ? I would show you the real code but would rather not do so...

Comment: The console rendering is a lie. Well, not really. But it exists only as the projection of the underlying model. The collision handling is part of that model (and not the display), however it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this.  I would expect you have a two-dimensional array representing the game map.  One simple method is to add a method `CheckMove` which validates an attempted move. If not valid, then the move is not performed.  Here's a sort of pseudo-code example.

```
public bool CheckMove(int newY, int newX) {
    if (grid[newY][newX] == WALL)
        return false;
    if (newY < 0 || newY > Y_MAX || newX < 0 || newX > X_MAX)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public void Move(int dir) {
    // calc new x & y

    if (!CheckMove(newY, newX)) return;

    // else do the move
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thanks so much.

Comment: Just one question, how would I go about making the console space one large array? Like if the console were 80x25 I would have an array 80x25 big.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

- Hold all the walls with their position in a HashSet or similar.
- check the direction the player wants to go and then check whether there is a wall or not.

I don't get it why it is that hard, maybe you could explain ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off - I have zero experience with console games however it seems to me that you should have a data model that contains the "map" the user is in and check it in the data model before you update the UI (console)

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not matters whether you write console application, or not. Because it's not purpose of View to detect collisions. It's purpose of your game Model. Model just displayed on the View. Internally walls structure could be described even as two-dimensional array. Current players coordinates also stored in model. Thus detecting possibility to move some where could look like:

```
public void IsPossibleMoveTo(int x, int y)
{
    return mazeArray[x, y] == null;
}
```